# Typescript generic type constraint from array of types

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics, type-constraints

I have an array of types declared as

```
const APIS = [NewsApi, CommentsApi, FileApi];
```

I want to have a method that accepts one of these types from that `APIS` array, like the following:

```
myMethod<T extends anyof APIS>(apiType: T): T {
    const api = new apiType(); //pseudo code, does not work off course
    // some common configuration code
    return api;
}
```

. I cannot do `myMethod<T extends NewsApi|CommentsApi>(): T`, as the APIS array is auto generated. Is this possible with typescript?

Update:

Aleksey's solution works great for passing in the input. However, the return type cannot be inferred from the usage.

```
const myApi = myMethod(NewsApi);
```

In above case, myApi is not of type `NewsApi`, but `NewsApi|CommentsApi|FileApi`.
Is it possible to set the return type explicitly to instance of input api type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can change definition of the array to readonly tuple:

```
const APIS = [NewsApi, CommentsApi, FileApi] as const;
```

then you can get union of possible array values using lookup type:

```
type ApiConstructors = typeof APIS[number];

function myMethod<T extends InstanceType<ApiConstructors>>(apiType: new () => T): T {
  return new apiType();
}

const api = myMethod(NewsApi); // api is of type NewsApi
```

[InstanceType](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#instancetypet) utility used to get instance type of a constructor function.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYGwhgzhAEByCmB3CBBADgS2gbwLAChpoBbARgC5owA7ATwG4CBfAg0SGAYQHtjj5qAF1SYcBIsQBMlGg2at87KNABiGEPHRY8hEgGYZdRvhb423ahEHQUABQCSAZWgBeaAG0EyLQBpoPPgFhX1V1TUwAXSoYYAsrYwJBWjR4G0weS0EAJwBXYEFuLJg3JJTuADMbB0d3ahziACN4LIiE-HKc6nyMCxJaAFl4QQALbgATAB4AFWh4AA9BATGYe0yaYHgp5PgJrQyrXPzCiAA+E4AKMEwtlMpqJGhzgEpXE+gpp8oZnSIsoZystRoPdEFRrttnsZTOZMmCsG5iAMhqMxucvCIME96NAAPQ4uHQDAwCrQUqpdFaBRKGAqbjcHDQUyIwYjcbnWncLG4-EAUTmKXy8DGsyyWUKQA)

Comment: Thank you @Aleksey :) . Also, would it be possible to set the return type of the method explicitly to an instance of api type? I understand that the return type will be implicitly inferred from the returned object. Just wondering, if it can also be set explicitly, just in case I am declaring an interface.

Comment: Just noticed that the return type is not exactly inferred from the usage. When I declare const myApi = myMethod(NewsApi); myApi is not inferred as NewsApi, but union of all apis.

Comment: I'll check this later, but that's not what you've asked originally 

Comment: I agree, I should have been more specific in the first place. Sorry for that. :)

Comment: @VictorMukherjee I've updated answer and playground